# Update values in a column while looping over through a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a script to extract some details from images. I am trying to loop over a dataframe that has my image names. How can I add a new column to the dataframe, that populates the extracted name appropriately against the image name?

```py
for image in df['images']:
    concatenated_name                    = ''.join(name)
    df.loc[image, df['images']]['names'] = concatenated_name
```

Expected:

```
Index images names
0     img_01 TonyStark
1     img_02 Thanos
2     img_03 Thor
```

Got:

```
Index images names
0     img_01 Thor
1     img_02 Thor
2     img_03 Thor
```

Comment: what is the value of name?

Comment: integer or string

Comment: why do you need a loop, why can't you just use column operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply a function on each row:

```
def get_name(image):
    # Code for getting the name
    return name

df['names'] = df['images'].apply(get_name)
```

---

Follwing your answer that added some more details, it should be possible to shorten it to:

```
def get_details(filename):
    image = os.getcwd() + filename
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image))
    .
    .
    . 
    data = ''.join(a) 
    return data

df['data'] = df['filenames'].apply(get_details)
# save df to csv / excel / other
```

Comment: Thanks Shaido! I tried this approach, but couldn't achieve the desired result. So, I kept researching and I believe I finally found a solution. Perhaps, I should have added more information about the issue I was facing. Thanks much!

Comment: @Loki: Nice that you could solve it :). I added an extension to my answer here following the information in your answer that should work for you, personally I think it looks a bit cleaner and you don't need to recreate the dataframe.

Comment: @Loki: Just noticed the new code didn't actually return a value... that should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple trials, I think I have a viable solution to this question.

I was using nested function for this exercise, such that function 1 loops over a dataframe of files and calls to function 2 to extract text, perform validation and return a value if the image had the expected field. 
First, I created an empty list which would be populated during each run of function 2. At the end, the user can choose to use this list to create a dataframe.

```
# dataframes to store data
df = pd.DataFrame(os.listdir(), columns=['filenames'])
df = df[df['filenames'].str.contains(".png|.jpg|.jpeg")]
df['filenames'] = '\\' + df['filenames']
df1 = [] #Empty list to record details 

# Function 1
def extract_details(df):
    for filename in df['filenames']:
        get_details(filename)

# Function 2
def get_details(filename):
    image = os.getcwd() + filename
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image))
    .
    .
    . 
    data = ''.join(a) 
    print(filename, data)
    df1.append([filename, data])

df_data = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['filenames', 'data']) # Container for final  output
df_data.to_csv('data_list.csv') # Write output to a csv file 
df_data.to_excel('data_list.xlsx') # Write output to an excel file
```